# Qprogressbar with two values

Tags: python, qt4, qprogressbar

I have some unusual question :
For visualization of packing progress i think about qprogressbar with two values in one bar - one showing bytes read, and another showing  write-out bytes, which gives also imagine about compress ratio.

It is possible with QT4 ?

Also, I have very little experience with C++ coding, my current work is based on Python, PyQT4,

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, but you will have to implement your own "DualValueProgressbar" here you have an example, **is not complete production code** but it will point to you in the right direction.

A note before continue:

Will this you will be able to show two values in the bar, but show two colours in the same bar is a very different thing. So I'll recomend you to use two prograssbar for doing what you want, keep it simple.

Before see any code let me explain what I did.

1. Subclass `QProgressBar`
2. Add a variable member called `self.__value_1`. This will be the second value.
3. Override the method `paintEvent` in order to draw `self.__value_1` inside the bar.

Recomendations:

1. Write code for establishing limits on the second value. (Minimun and maximun)
2. Write code for handle the `format` property.
3. Write code for habdle the aligment property.

This is the result:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class DualValueProgressBar(QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DualValueProgressBar, self).__init__(parent)

        # The other value you want to show
        self.__value_1 = 0

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # Paint the parent.
        super(DualValueProgressBar, self).paintEvent(event)
        # In the future versions if your custom object you
        # should use this to set the position of the value_1
        # in the progressbar, right now I'm not using it.
        aligment = self.alignment()
        geometry = self.rect() # You use this to set the position of the text.
        # Start to paint.
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.drawText(geometry.center().x() + 20, geometry.center().y() + qp.fontMetrics().height()/2.0, "{0}%".format(str(self.value1)))
        qp.end()

    @property
    def value1(self):
        return self.__value_1

    @pyqtSlot("int")
    def setValue1(self, value):
        self.__value_1 = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    hlayout = QHBoxLayout(window)
    dpb = DualValueProgressBar(window)
    dpb.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
    # This two lines are important.
    dpb.setValue(20)
    dpb.setValue1(10)  # Look you can set another value.
    hlayout.addWidget(dpb)
    window.setLayout(hlayout)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Finally the code sample: